# Use a value from a field that use to be a NULL value but changed during running query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table look like this

```
    dt               |   pname  |   diff   |   total
2020-10-12 20:00:00       A         5           100
2020-10-12 20:15:00       A         10          110
2020-10-12 20:30:00       A         15          NULL
2020-10-12 20:45:00       A         10          NULL
```

What I wanted to do is to replace null value into a value of `current row diff sum with total value of a row that is the previous 15 minute of the same name (only a row that is NULL)`

So, I write a case when condition and sum the value like this:

```
SELECT dt, pname, diff,
CASE WHEN (LAG(dt,1) OVER
(partition by pname order by dt)) =  dt - interval '15 minutes' and total is null 
THEN diff + ((LAG(total,1) OVER (partition by pname order by dt)))
else total end as total 
FROM table_name;
```

So, I exepect result to be like this:

```
         dt          |   pname  |   diff   |   total
2020-10-12 20:00:00       A         5           100
2020-10-12 20:15:00       A         10          110
2020-10-12 20:30:00       A         15          125
2020-10-12 20:45:00       A         10          135
```

But then the result is:

```
         dt          |   pname  |   diff   |   total
2020-10-12 20:00:00       A         5           100
2020-10-12 20:15:00       A         10          110
2020-10-12 20:30:00       A         15          125
2020-10-12 20:45:00       A         10          NULL
```

which the last row value still be null. I think it because the original table value is null, that's why this query end up like this. Do I miss something? I want this value to be updated to the existing table (or maybe a new table created for this)

Comment: You are missing the fact that `LAG(total,1)` for the last row will return `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am considering that you have records for each 15 min. You need `sum` and `first_value` analytical function as follows:

```
SELECT dt, pname, diff,
       CASE WHEN total is null 
            THEN first_value(total - diff) OVER (partition by pname order by dt) 
                 + sum(diff) OVER (partition by pname order by dt)
            else total 
       end as total 
  FROM table_name;
```

Comment: The 3rd row that total value supposed to be 15+110 = 125 but end up return 130. Not sure if there is something wrong in this query

Comment: Got the correct result now. May I ask why these functions are needed?

Comment: As your requirement demands. you need last record value if current record total value is null but what if the last value is null too. So that is why we started creating the total from first record so that this can be used whenver we find bull value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you care about the existing values at all -- except for the first one:

```
select t.*,
       (first_value(total - diff) over (partition by pname order by dt) +
        sum(diff) over (partition by pname order by dt)
       ) as new_total
from t;
```

If the existing totals do not agree with the calculation, then you should ask a *new* question and provide sample data and an explanation of the logic.